# BigQuery select statement alias is not working in where clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried given below query, but it throw error RANK is not defined.

```
SELECT
    EmailAddress
  , FirstName
  , LastName
  , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BookingDate) AS RANK FROM `table_name`
WHERE RANK BETWEEN 5 AND 7
```

Comment: how can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: *"how can I achieve this requirement?"*  Now idea in what Server and or version is running... As the current SQL code is MySQL and Google BigGoogle Standard SQL compatible..   Google BigGoogle Standard SQL should have `RANK()` function defined and MySQL 8.0 has well.. *"

I tried given below query, but it throw error RANK is not defined."* Can you atleast copy and paste the error as errors can be used for database identification

Comment: I'm using bigqery BigQuery

Comment: *"I'm using bigqery BigQuery"* Then it sounds like you need to [Enable Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

WHERE clause is evaluated before output of query is formed and assigned aliases, which means that field `rank` is not available at a time when `WHERE rank BETWEEN 5 AND 7`.

You just need to use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
      EmailAddress
    , FirstName
    , LastName
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BookingDate) AS rank 
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE rank BETWEEN 5 AND 7
```